# azure ml web service return internal error

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I deployed a web service of multiclass decision forest, but when i tested it, just kept getting this returned:

Error code: InternalError, Http status code: 500

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The way to create web service is to first create predictive experiment, then set the web service ports around score module (not trained module). Once ports are set, then publish web service

Here is documentation describing how to create web service - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-model-progression-experiment-to-web-service/

Here is the working example for your solution - http://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Binary-Classfication-Credit-risk-prediction-Predictive-Exp-3

[image]